# Changes to data through strings recognized as variable in R

Tags: r, variables, reference

I have a variable x that contains variable names for 10 matrices. So variable `a` to `j` contains different matrices.

```
x = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

I would like to change the column names on all of these matrices. I've used functions eval(parse()) and get() such as

```
>   get(i)[0,] = n 
Error in get(i)[0, ] = n : could not find function "get<-"

>   colnames(eval(parse(text = i))) = n
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'a': No such file or directory
```

where `n` contains the column names that I want for the matrix and `i` is the looping variable. edit: `n` is a column name that was obtained from the first row of `a` to `j`, which changes in every loop.

```
for (i in x){
   n = get(i)[1,]
   # insert column changing codes
}
```

Is there a way to change the column name from a variable that was called from the string of another variable?

**Edit1:**

To clarify, I was trying to do data manipulation and modelling across a group of `matrices`/`data frames`. In this case, I specifically wanted to change the `column name` of the matrices, the column name of the matrices are contained in the first of the the respective matrix so every matrix have a different set of column name. Using another `vector` / `matrix` containing the names of these matrices, I was intending to `loop` through the names to refer to the `matrix` and then change the column name of these matrices specifically.

While waiting for answers I somehow found a method which may not be the most efficient nor work in most scenario but seems to be relatively simpler to me:

```
y = get(i)
colnames(y) = n
assign((paste(i)), y)
```

This will be looped from `a` to `j`.

Thank you for the comments and answers.

Comment: You will make your life *a lot* easier if you store these objects in a `list` instead of having them float around freely in your global environment. If you have a `list` of `matrix` objects, you could then easily operate on them using functions from the `*apply` family. If you elaborate on what you're trying to do, I'm sure we can provide a relevant example. At the moment this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to do Y, whereas the issue is really X (i.e. the fact that your objects are not in a `list`).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Okay thanks for the pointers. Actually I was trying to do data manipulation and modelling across a group of `matrices`/`data frames`. Using another `vector` / `matrix` containing the names of these matrices, I was intending to loop through the names to refer to the `matrix` and then apply various functions to these matrices.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Maurits Evers a good way to solve the problem is to get data in a list. You can use `mget` to get matrices in a list and change the column names.

```
list_mat <- lapply(mget(x), function(mat) {colnames(mat) <- n;mat})
```

If you want the changed matrices in global environment again, you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(list_mat, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Using a reproducible example,

```
a <- matrix(1:16, 4)
colnames(a) <- letters[1:4]
b <- a
n <- letters[9:12]
x <- c('a', 'b')
```

Using `lapply` :

```
list_mat <- lapply(mget(x), function(mat) {colnames(mat) <- n;mat})
list_mat

#$a
#     i j  k  l
#[1,] 1 5  9 13
#[2,] 2 6 10 14
#[3,] 3 7 11 15
#[4,] 4 8 12 16

#$b
#     i j  k  l
#[1,] 1 5  9 13
#[2,] 2 6 10 14
#[3,] 3 7 11 15
#[4,] 4 8 12 16
```

Comment: May i know how does `function(mat) {colnames(mat) <- n;mat}` work in lapply? I could only understand when a normal function such as `as.numeric` was used. Thanks alot

Comment: @Qlwkejrh `colnames(mat) <- n` changes the column name of each matrix to `n` and `mat` returns the changed matrix back.